# Doctrine2 - 3 tables relation - Select

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have a relation that looks like this:

Category <=== Host <===> User

Basically User-Host is a many-to-many relation, and each Host have one Category (one-to-many).

Somehow I need to list what Categories a User has hosts in. Something like:

Select Categories From Categories Where Host Has User == MyUser.

So far I can only list what Hosts a User has, and what Category a Host has. With plain SQL I need 2 Joins, but cant find out a way to do it with Doctrine 2. I have been playin all day with QueryBuilder but am not even close yet.

Any tips on this?

Comment: You said you've been trying all day; what are some of the things you tried and what was wrong with each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DQL:

```
SELECT c
FROM Entity\User u
INNER JOIN u.hosts h
INNER JOIN h.category c
WHERE u.id = :user
```

That should do the trick.